# protobuf-net port to .net core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, protobuf-net

I need google protocol buffers on .net core 2.0. 
I am aware the official google proto buffer implementation is not available on .net core 2.0, but is [protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net) can be ported over to .net core 2.0?

I tried porting it myself and I see the library uses AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly which is not ported to .net core yet.

Also how is the [.net WEBAPIController](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib.Core/tree/master/src/WebApiContrib.Core.Formatter.Protobuf) uses google protocol buffer with?

Comment: "I am aware the official google proto buffer implementation is not available on .net core 2.0" - um, it should work fine. We target netstandard1.3, so it should be fine. Give your title, I think you may be confused between ".NET Core 2.0" (2017) and ".NET 2.0" (2005).

Comment: Additionally, your final sentence should be in a separate question, and with *much* more detail. It's extremely unclear what you mean.

Comment: Thanks Jon, that was a typo and I've fixed it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Protobuf-net on nuget already supports net standard 1.3 and above, which includes what you need. There is nothing you should need to do to use protobuf-net.

Comment: Thanks I am trying to compile myself using .net 2.0 by downloading the source via GitHub, do I need to do anything extra to successfully compile it?

Comment: @RohitSharma "dotnet build" should work...