# protobuf-net 2.4.0 for .NET Standard 2.0 not fully compatible

Tags: protobuf-net, .net-standard-2.0

I built the [protobuf-net 2.4.0](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/releases/tag/2.4.0) project for .Net Standard 2.0 but the [portability-analyzer tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer) shows only 92% of compatibility because of the below details.

[image]

Questions are:

1. Can I use it in every .NETCore, .NETFramework, and .NET projects anyway? (I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50831936/4396321) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46509922/4396321) posts, but with the test just described I'd like to be sure it's so)
2. Is there a protobuf-net version fully compatible with .Net Standard 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, confusingly, impossible to talk about compatibility with .NET Standard, unless you mean "lowest common denominator", which: most people don't. What matters is *what you actually run it on*. You mention .NET Framework and .NET Core - and it should.work just fine there. If you were using it on Unity or Xamarin (mobile etc), the answer is more complicated.

Comment: Currently, I use it in a .NetFramework library that is used in a .NetFramework 4.7.2 application. Soon the application will be built also for .NetCore 3.1 and (maybe) for .Net6 for cross-platform deployment purposes, so I checked my library and it seems to be 100% .NetStandard 2.0 compatible except for protobuf-net. Do you think I could have some problems with O.S. different than Windows?

Comment: @ilCosmico It isn't about the OS; it is about the framework. All of the frameworks you mention should be absolutely fine. Also note: .NET Standard is a *library reference*; when you build an *application*, it re-evaluates the transitive dependencies and ships the most appropriate version for the *application*; that means that on net472 you'll get the net461 build, on netcoreapp 3.1 you'll get the netcoreapp3.1 build, and on net6 you'll get the net5 build, because protobuf-net has those targets (see "Dependencies" in nuget)

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I can't still understand why the Microsoft tool tells that some namespaces are supported only by NetStandard2.1 and the project is correctly built with NetStandard2.0 anyway, but the below link confirms that it's supported by Unity and Xamarin as well... Cool!
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/dotnet-standard

Comment: @ilCosmico it is more complicated than a table can show; not everything works the same on Xamarin iOS, for example

Comment: I can understand that it's not so easy and I think the best would be always native app according to the platform of course :)